# How to make parskip in minipage match that of parskip outside minipage?

Tags: minipage, paragraphs, article, parskip

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam scelerisque
purus eget arcu eleifend semper. Curabitur sagittis eleifend augue.
Maecenas lobortis eget elit ac tempor. Nam ipsum sem, accumsan nec
iaculis ut, tempus vel magna.

Nam dolor risus, posuere ut tempus vel, malesuada quis elit. Sed vel
ligula at nisl lacinia feugiat et in tellus. Donec ullamcorper
vestibulum ante, ac efficitur neque vulputate nec.

\begin{minipage}{0.50\linewidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam scelerisque
purus eget arcu eleifend semper. Curabitur sagittis eleifend augue.
Maecenas lobortis eget elit ac tempor. Nam ipsum sem, accumsan nec
iaculis ut, tempus vel magna.

Nam dolor risus, posuere ut tempus vel, malesuada quis elit. Sed vel
ligula at nisl lacinia feugiat et in tellus. Donec ullamcorper
vestibulum ante, ac efficitur neque vulputate nec.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

The vertical space between paragraphs in `minipage` is different from the vertical space between paragraphs outside `minipage`. How can I make the paragraphs in `minipage` with that outside `minipage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
\setlength{\skip0}{\parskip}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\setlength\parskip{\skip0}
```

Although if the example is representative of the actual document, I would not use a minipage here but rather a display environment that increases the right margin (like `quote` but just indenting on the right).